# Как выглядит блок-схема с вызовом функции внутри условия

Tags: c, блок-схема

Как отобразить в блок-схеме фрагмент кода `if (d<1 || d>amountofdays(m))`, написанный на языке C?

Comment: а как вообще в языке Си блок-схемы выглядят?

Comment: @Grundy Тут подразумевается, что часть кода на языке Си и ее переводят в блоксхему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от требуемого уровня детализации алгоритма.

Если функцию `amountofdays` считать элементарной, то это будет один блок "Решение" (ромб), где следует так и написать: `d<1 || d>amountofdays(m)`.

Если же нужно подчеркнуть вызов `amountofdays` как подпрограммы - то придется раскрывать все языковые конструкции. Будет сначала блок "Решение" для условия `d<1`, потом блок "Предопределенный процесс" для вызова `d0 := amountofdays(m)` и наконец еще один блок "Решение" с проверкой `d>d0`.

PS но, вообще говоря, блок-схема на данных момент является самым глупым из вариантов документации к коду. Из-за того самого уровня детализации, который стабильно оказывается ниже чем у, собственно, кода. Если это не учебное задание, то лучше поискать другие способы визуализации (например, UML или какой-нибудь IDEF).

Comment: Спасибо большое за столь содержательный ответ. Задание учебное. Могу уточнить, т.е. нужно просто из одного условия по сути сделать два и вставить между ними сам блок вызова (предопр. процесс)? Вот именно интересует порядок действий, который в итоге осуществляет программа.

Comment: @Difmus проблема всех учебных заданий - ответ на них сильно зависит от преподавателя, и это не исключение.

Comment: @Difmus а по поводу порядка выполнения - гуглите короткое замыкание логических операторов

Answer (score 0):

Да как и в любом другом языке.

Ромб, внутри него пишешь условие d<1 || d>amountofdays(m) .
От Ромба идёт 2 линии с двух сторон. 
Над первой линией пишешь true, над второй false.
Ну и в зависимости от того какой ответ возвращает дальше идёт уже или ромб - если ещё условие дальше идёт, или квадрат - если выполняется команды какие-либо.

Comment: Только условие if в блок-схеме вроде выглядит ромбом, так мы на практике еще в школе обозначали. Или что-то поменялось уже?

Comment: так-то это один "квадрат" должен быть

Comment: @Jenssen , да точно, давно было,забыл. Исправлю :)

Comment: Мне необходимо отдельно обозначить действия функции как подпрограммы. Ведь, я полагаю, в блок-схеме необходим блок "предопределенный процессор" с вызовом функции в любом случае, если она присутствует? Но вызов заключен в блоке с условием, поэтому я не знаю, как это обозначить, и в каком вообще порядке будет условие выполняться, когда программа вообще обращается к функции. Надеюсь, поняли, о чем я говорю)